# Merging dynamic ranges into one Range Excel or VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge, range

I am currently trying to take two ranges and combine them into one range. My ranges are dynamic because they change based off the date. For example, Suppose the two ranges I want to combine are A3:A10 and the other C7:C12. And every day it refreshes and moves the index by 1... so the new ranges are A4:A11 and C8:C13. I want to combine the two into one range into a different column. I am assuming that this will have to be implemented in vba... however, I have been having minimal luck. I have values that indicate what row number I want to make my ranges within my worksheet. I've tried making VBA macros, but I have been having no luck. I keep getting 9(the first term of the range I wanted) as my result and not a range, but I want to use the function to print the whole combined range. I have also thought about using Sub, but I am not very experienced in using Sub.

Here's what I have so far... Please let me know any suggestions or tips.

```
Function FiveYTwoY()
 Worksheets("India Data").Activate
 index5_90 = Cells(10, 2).Value '5Y 90 day index
 index5_yes = Cells(9, 2).Value '5Y yesterday index
 index2_90 = Cells(7, 2).Value  '2Y 90 day index
 index2_yes = Cells(6, 2).Value '2Y yesterday index
 Dim range5 As Range
 Set range5 = Range(Cells(index5_90, 20), Cells(index5_yes, 20))

 Dim range2 As Range
 Set range2 = Range(Cells(index2_90, 17), Cells(index2_yes, 17))
 FiveYTwoY = Union(range2, range5)

End Function
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: No, I believe we are talking about different things.

Comment: Do you need `Function FiveYTwoY() as Range`? Use F8 (single cycle) and `Debug.Print range5.Address`, etc.

Comment: No, I don't believe so. It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the use of `.Select/Activate`. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179). Fully qualify your objects.

Also you have to use `Set` to assign ranges as shown below

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim range5 As Range, range2 As Range, FiveYTwoY As Range

    With Worksheets("India Data")
        index5_90 = .Cells(10, 2).Value '5Y 90 day index
        index5_yes = .Cells(9, 2).Value '5Y yesterday index
        index2_90 = .Cells(7, 2).Value  '2Y 90 day index
        index2_yes = .Cells(6, 2).Value '2Y yesterday index

        Set range5 = .Range(.Cells(index5_90, 20), .Cells(index5_yes, 20))
        Set range2 = .Range(.Cells(index2_90, 17), .Cells(index2_yes, 17))

        Set FiveYTwoY = Union(range2, range5)

        With FiveYTwoY
            '
            '~~> Do whatever you want with that range here
            '
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I will see if this works. How would I print the range into a worksheet?

Comment: `FiveYTwoY.Copy DestRng`

Comment: for some reason it is saying Sub undefined... not sure why

Comment: something wrong with my DestRng. I'll figure it out. Thanks so much you've been awesome!

Comment: `DestRng` is an example. It is the destination range where you have to paste. For example `FiveYTwoY.Copy Worksheets("India Data").Range("A40")`

Comment: Sorry to bother you.... but I am getting that command cannot be used on multiple selections when I try to copy fiveYtwoY

Comment: Ah yes. My apologies. So where do you want to copy them?

Comment: I want to copy the whole range and paste it into a selected cell. Is this possible? Thats why I wanted a function, but that's probably not possible right?

Comment: I ended up doing this in python, but if you figure it out please let me know. Thanks again for your help I really appreciate all the time you put in to help me.